# Another option to make an attack like on Burp suite intruder

Tags: http, metasploit, backtrack-linux, burp

I has been using Burp Suite for making http requests and grabbing the payload from a .csv file,
I want to know how can i do this using another software or what is the name of the attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which module of Burp are you using ? Burp is an intercepting proxy and intercepts all the requests made by your browser.

Another popular intercepting proxy is OWASP ZAP. Google it.

Comment: Yes im using the intercept proxy then i send the http requests intercepted to the intruter i add an csv and it does all the requests for each valué on the csv